# How it is possible to observe stream of bool values with delay on value change?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactive

I have speed observer that looks like this (it is simple version to describe problem):

```
class SpeedManager {
    var speed = Variable(0.0)
    private var limit = 0.2

    func speedObserver() -> Observable<Bool> {
        return speed.asObservable().map{$0 >= self.limit}
    }
}
```

What I do I just validate speed if limit is reached.

So I receive this kind of stream:

### false----->true----->false----->true----->true----->true----->true

Than I do this:

```
let speedManager = SpeedManager()

let observable = speedManager.speedObserver().distinctUntilChanged()
```

Where `observable` will retrun this kind of stream:

### false----->true----->false----->true----->false-----> true----->false

So I just need to add step that will validate if `observable` event is `true` and it is true during 10 seconds.

Basically if `observable` next event is `true` I should wait 10 seconds to validate if next event would not be `false`.

Comment: You could use `throttle` or `debounce` have a look at this article https://medium.com/@dkhuong291/throttle-vs-debounce-in-rxswift-86f8b303d5d4

Comment: @sbarow I am not sure that it is right approach to create delay on value change but I will take a look. The main point how can I combine debounce with value change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. Let me explain. You wrote:

> So I just need to add step that will validate if observable event is
>   true and it is true during 10 seconds.

It describes two situations:

- Only first `true` event is considered to trigger the 10 seconds timer. Each next `true` event is ignored and doesn't produce timer until `false` event cancels the timer.
- Each `true` event should produce `observable` which waits 10 seconds for any `false` event and if `false` doesn't happen - your observable fires.

The 1st situation is simple:

```
let observable1 = observable
    .debounce(10, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .filter({ $0 == true })
    .share(replay: 1, scope: SubjectLifetimeScope.whileConnected)
```

The 2nd situation is harder:

```
let observableEnumerated = observable
    .scan((false, 0)) { (value, next) -> (Bool, Int) in
        return (next, value.1 + 1)
    }
    .share(replay: 1, scope: SubjectLifetimeScope.whileConnected)
let observableEnumeratedFalse = observableEnumerated
    .filter({ $0.0 == false })
    .share(replay: 1, scope: SubjectLifetimeScope.whileConnected)
let observable1 = observableEnumerated
    .filter({ $0.0 == true })
    .delay(10, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .withLatestFrom(observableEnumeratedFalse){(trueIndex: $0.1, falseIndex: $1.1)}
    .filter({ $0.trueIndex > $0.falseIndex })
    .share(replay: 1, scope: SubjectLifetimeScope.whileConnected)
```

`observableEnumerated` - just enumerates your `Bool` observable

`observableEnumeratedFalse` - takes only `false` enumerated events

Then you take only `true` events. Delay each of them for 10 seconds. After the delay you take the last value from `false` enumerated observable. And if last `false` event has index lower then the current delayed `true` event - that is what you need.

The 2nd situation wasn't tested, it just shows an approach to deal with the task. Most of the time 1st solution using `debounce` will be your choice. Btw, `throttle` is not very suitable in such situation, read their descriptions to fully understand their possibilities.